# execute bash script inside deploy.rb using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am learning (by doing) *Rails* and *Capistrano*.

How can I execute a scrpit inside **deploy.rb**?

I came across `run(command)`, `exec(command)`, `execute:` or `run:`.

I don't have to specify **:db** or **web** so I have the following backbone:

```
task :myTask do
    on roles(:app) do 
      execute "bash myScript.sh"
      puts "#{:server} reports: #{myTask}"
    end
  end
```

1. Is this correct?
2. Is the ssh part of the whole process or I have to ssh in the command?
3. How do people develope `deploy.rb` without `cap deploy` every time they make a change?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby allows you to run a shell script using `backtick`

for example

```rb
output = `pwd`
puts "output is #{output}"
```

see more https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
role :app, 'user@domain1.com'

on roles(:app) do
  within 'remote_path' do
    execute 'bash', ' myScript.sh'
  end
end
```